# Tire sidewall tear - can it be glued?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

[image]

Hi, I know the standard response is any sidewall damage replace the tire. These are brand new tires and as you will see no cord or steel showing. 
Can I just superglue the flap down?

Comment: The width is 11mm

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As far as a "standard answer" of "you must replace", that isn't always a given. I'd answer your question, but I can't see the images at work. If the question is still lingering after I get home, I'll take a look and give you my opinion. Usually, as long as there's no cords showing, no bulging/deformities, or pressure loss over time, the tire is usually good to go.

Comment: I wouldn't use any kind of cyanoacrylate (superglue); they're too brittle and need moisture to activate.

Comment: Any ideas what glue would be best?

Comment: Use some [shoe goo](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Shoe-Goo-Shoe-Repair-Adhesive-3-7oz-Clear/21129799).